# Does gear purchased with justice point still require reputation

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Does the gear purchased with justice points still require reputation from faction ?

Answer (score 1):

For Mist of Pandaria:

- Itemlevel 496 epic gear from the the Dominance Offensive / Operation Shieldwall (Krasarang Wilds) **does not require reputation anymore** but you have to do the start quests to access the vendor
- Itemlevel 489 epic gear from the general vendor at the Niuzao Temple **does not require reputation** anymore (this gear originally needed Valor points and reputation from the different factions of Pandaria)
- Itemlevel 458 blue gear from the general vendor at the Niuzao Temple **does not require reputation** anymore (this gear originally needed reputation from the different factions of Pandaria)

Justice gear and former Valor gear from previous expansions generally **does not require reputation** anymore and only costs Justice points now.

Answer (score 0):

Generally?  Yes.

Though you could be a little more specific as to what faction or at least what vendor you're referring to.